# Fluent NHibernate Custom SQL Query

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate and FNH. I'm trying to query for multiple possible objects in a single query and I am not sure what the most efficient query is. I have a dictionary of words:

```
public class Word
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to query for all Word objects that are contained in a list. The SQL I have is:

```
SELECT (*) FROM dbo.Word WHERE Text LIKE 'word1%' OR Text LIKE 'word2%' ...
```

Right now I'm just getting the list of words and generating the `WHERE` clause of the SQL query. I've created an `ISQLQuery` but I'm not sure how to execute it and get back a collection of Word objects.

Comment: Did you forget the "%" in your sample query?  It makes a difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using NHibernate why not use the facilities provided for you rather than writing custom SQL that is likely prone to SQL injection.

```
public IList<Word> GetWords(IList<string> filters)
{
    var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Word>();
    var disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        disjunction.Add(Restrictions.Like("Text", filter, MatchMode.Start));
    }
    criteria.Add(disjunction);

    return criteria.List<Word>();
}
```

Comment: @Yads When I run using that approach, I get an exception: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

Comment: Well the user is inputting effectively limitless text and I want to pull all valid words out. For this specific test case, I think I'm only doing around 200.

Comment: @Wesley, try the updated code, however, you shouldn't allow unlimited query parameters.

Comment: @Yads Excellent, it works! Thank you! What would you recommend I do instead of unlimited query parameters? Split them up into chunks of N (not sure what a good N is)?

Comment: @Wesley, not sure what your app does, but if possible just prevent the user from entering more than x words. You'll need to play around to figure out a good value for x.

Comment: +1 for disjunction.  I never knew it existed and it looks sweet!